# DAX measure - show values from best day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have, in PowerBI (October 2017 release) some data showing the snapshotted output of some solar panels at five-minute intervals.

[image: 'Solar Output' table containing three columns: Production (KW): numeric, Date: date, Time: time]

I presently have a measure which calculates the total production for each day by getting a sum of the instantaneous readings for the day and dividing by 12 (because there are 12 readings per hour) and then shows the average of this daily amount over whichever period is in the current context:

```
Avg Daily Production (KWh) = 
    AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE('Solar Output', 'Solar Output'[Date], "Daily Production (KWh)", SUM('Solar Output'[Production (KW)]/12), [Daily Production (KWh)])
```

For my visualisations I'd like to show a chart which displays the average production at various times of the day compared to the production at that time for the best day, i.e. the day with the highest value for `[Avg Daily Production (KWh)]`.

Here is my working so far:

Identify the top day by using

```
Best Day = TOPN(1, SUMMARIZE('Solar Output', 'Solar Output'[Date], "Daily Production (KWh)", [Avg Daily Production (KWh)]), [Daily Production (KWh)], DESC)
```

But this produces a row, not a scalar, and I can't quite work out how to just get this date and use it as a filter for a measure like this:

```
Production On Best Day (KW) = 
    CALCULATE(SUM([Production (KW)]), FILTER(ALL('Solar Output'[Date]), 'Solar Output'[Date] = [Best Day]))
```

[image: desired solution]

The chart I want would look like this, with the average production for the selected dates in green and then another series showing the production at those times on the best day pencilled in red.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a sample .pbix file / dataset?

Comment: Unfamiliar with posting files here, I will just learn how...

Comment: Sorry, I have issues connecting to file hosting sites at work. Similar data can be found here https://pvoutput.org/intraday.jsp?id=53465&sid=48701&dt=20171018

Comment: I think the FIRSTNONBLANK function would work, e.g. wrapped around your Best Day expression. I'm not 100% certain and dont have time to play around with it today, but HTH.

Comment: @MikeHoney `FIRSTNONBLANK(ColumnName, Expression)` requires a column reference as an argument but `TOPN()` returns a table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't really get my head around the calculations involved but I hope I get your requirement.

So you want to plot two lines on the same chart, one always being the data from the best day as reference, and the other one the data selected from the date filter, right?

You're actually pretty closed to the solution with the info given above.

I just modified your DAX to:

```
Production On Best Day (KW) = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Solar Output'[Average]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Solar Output'[Date]),
        'Solar Output'[Date] = VALUES('Best Day'[Date])
    )
)
```

(Not quite sure how you compute your intermediate measures so you may need to adjust according to your measures)

Yes, `TOPN()` returns a table, so you can get the date value using `VALUES('Best Day'[Date])` and use it for comparison.

Results:

[image: result1]
[image: result2]

Comment: So instead of `Best Day` being a measure, I can make it as a calculated table.... ?

Comment: Do you have data of multiple solar panels in the same table? Or put it in another way, will your `Best Day` change according to other filters?

Comment: No, currently the value will be the same regardless of other filters.

Comment: Slight modification: `Production On Best Day (KWh) = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Production (KW)]), FILTER(ALL('Solar Output'[Date].[Date]), 'Solar Output'[Date].[Date] = VALUES('Best Day'[Date])))` something to do with using the implicit date hierarchy correctly I think.

Comment: Then this solution should work. Otherwise, we'll need a solution with `Best Day` being `measure` because the calculated table will only be refreshed when the data set is refreshed and will stay static during report consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach to solve this issue is to use the `MAXX()` function to get a scalar value out of the the table returned by `TOPN()`.

This works where `MAX()` doesn't because `MAXX()` accepts a table *expression* as its first argument (the table expression is the result of the `TOPN()` function) where `MAX()` only takes columns from existing tables.

```
Best Day = MAXX(TOPN(1, 
                     SUMMARIZE(ALL('Solar Output'), 
                               'Solar Output'[Date], 
                               "Daily Production (KWh)", 
                               [Avg Daily Production (KWh)]), 
                     [Daily Production (KWh)], 
                     DESC), 
                [Date])
```

The benefit of this approach is that it should work in versions of DAX with no calculated table support (e.g. SSAS 2014, Excel 2013).